# Get quarter of year in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this methodes to get the beginning and ending of the quarter for a specific date:

```
@date.beginning_of_quarter
@date.end_of_quarter
```

But how can i get the beginning ending of for eg. the 4 quarter of the year 2012? Without having to pass a date that is in the middle of the 4 quarter of 2012 to `end_of_quarter`? Thanks

Comment: Your question it's definitely not clear. None of the methods you references requires you to pass an argument.

Comment: I simply want the nbeginning and end date for the 4 quarter in 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Date.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) (negative numbers count from the end):

```
require 'date'

# 1st quarter
Date.new(2012, 1)      #=> #<Date: 2012-01-01 ...>
Date.new(2012, 3, -1)  #=> #<Date: 2012-03-31 ...>

# 2nd quarter
Date.new(2012, 4)      #=> #<Date: 2012-04-01 ...>
Date.new(2012, 6, -1)  #=> #<Date: 2012-06-30 ...>

# 3rd quarter
Date.new(2012, 7)      #=> #<Date: 2012-07-01 ...>
Date.new(2012, 9, -1)  #=> #<Date: 2012-09-30 ...>

# 4th quarter
Date.new(2012, 10)     #=> #<Date: 2012-10-01 ...>
Date.new(2012, 12, -1) #=> #<Date: 2012-12-31 ...>
```

Or as methods:

```
require 'date'

def beginning_of_quarter(year, quarter)
  Date.new(year, quarter * 3 - 2)
end

def end_of_quarter(year, quarter)
  Date.new(year, quarter * 3, -1)
end

beginning_of_quarter(2012, 4) #=> #<Date: 2012-10-01 ...>
end_of_quarter(2012, 4)       #=> #<Date: 2012-12-31 ...>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
Date.new(Date.today.year,12,1).beginning_of_quarter
Date.new(Date.today.year,12,1).end_of_quarter
```

The `Date.today.year` is there to make sure that it calls the last quarter of the current year.

Since you need it for the last quarter of 2012, you could do it this way instead:

```
Date.new(2012.year,12,1).beginning_of_quarter
Date.new(2012.year,12,1).end_of_quarter
```